# Spring Cloud Bus Kafka Bean Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config

I'm not very fond of using application.yml or bootstrap.yml in my configurations.

Do you know any class that can be used as a bean in order to configure the properties below?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    bus:     
      enabled: true
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: localhost:9092
          brokers: localhost:2181
```

My goal was to get something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class myConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Object myCloudBusConfig() {
    Object config = new Object();
    config.setCloudBusEnabled(true);
    return config;
  }

}
```

Also, as a future reference (and probably more trickier), how can I determine/found which classes refers to a specific property? Is there a correlation between the property name and the source package?

This would be of great help to me :)

Comment: It's not Spring Cloud Bus configuration,  but Spring Cloud Stream that bus is built on. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.java